# Outline shader of connected objects in projected context?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I am trying to modify the OutlinePass in threejs to outline the connected objects in clip space(after projection matrix). It can be separated in 3D space, but if it is connected after projection, it is assumed to be connected.

Original

[image: Original]

After Outline Pass

[image: after outlinepass]

I want to outline only the objects connected to the object selected with the mouse.

Now, I succeeded in drawing the outlines of the objects in the projection state.

When the middle object is selected with the mouse, the torusgeometry object on the left side of the example image does not want to draw an outline.

Is there a good way to do this? Any other methods or examples are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found an answer that doesn't look good at performance but shows the right visuals!

OutlinePass was modified using the flood fill algorithm.

```
import {
    AdditiveBlending,
    Color,
    DataTexture,
    DoubleSide,
    LinearFilter,
    Matrix4,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    MeshDepthMaterial,
    NoBlending,
    RGBADepthPacking,
    RGBAFormat,
    ShaderMaterial,
    UniformsUtils,
    Vector2,
    Vector3,
    Vector4,
    WebGLRenderTarget
} from '../../../build/three.module.js';
import { Pass } from '../postprocessing/Pass.js';
import { CopyShader } from '../shaders/CopyShader.js';

var OutlinePass = function (resolution, scene, camera, selectedObjects, ignoreObjects, mouse) {

    this.renderScene = scene;
    this.renderCamera = camera;
    this.selectedObjects = selectedObjects !== undefined ? selectedObjects : [];
    this.ignoreObjects = ignoreObjects !== undefined ? ignoreObjects : [];
    this.mouse = mouse !== undefined ? mouse : new Vector2(0, 0);
    this.visibleEdgeColor = new Color(1, 1, 1);
    this.edgeGlow = 0.0;
    this.edgeThickness = 1.0;
    this.edgeStrength = 3.0;
    this.downSampleRatio = 2;
    this.pulsePeriod = 0;

    this._visibilityCache = new Map();

    Pass.call(this);

    this.resolution = (resolution !== undefined) ? new Vector2(resolution.x, resolution.y) : new Vector2(256, 256);

    var pars = { minFilter: LinearFilter, magFilter: LinearFilter, format: RGBAFormat };

    var resx = Math.round(this.resolution.x / this.downSampleRatio);
    var resy = Math.round(this.resolution.y / this.downSampleRatio);

    this.maskBufferMaterial = new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
    this.maskBufferMaterial.side = DoubleSide;
    this.renderTargetMaskBuffer = new WebGLRenderTarget(this.resolution.x, this.resolution.y, pars);
    this.renderTargetMaskBuffer.texture.name = 'OutlinePass.mask';
    this.renderTargetMaskBuffer.texture.generateMipmaps = false;

    this.prepareMaskMaterial = this.getPrepareMaskMaterial();
    this.prepareMaskMaterial.side = DoubleSide;

    this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer = new WebGLRenderTarget(resx, resy, pars);
    this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer.texture.name = 'OutlinePass.depthDownSample';
    this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer.texture.generateMipmaps = false;

    this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1 = new WebGLRenderTarget(resx, resy, pars);
    this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1.texture.name = 'OutlinePass.blur1';
    this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1.texture.generateMipmaps = false;
    this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2 = new WebGLRenderTarget(Math.round(resx / 2), Math.round(resy / 2), pars);
    this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2.texture.name = 'OutlinePass.blur2';
    this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2.texture.generateMipmaps = false;

    this.edgeDetectionMaterial = this.getEdgeDetectionMaterial();
    this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1 = new WebGLRenderTarget(resx, resy, pars);
    this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.texture.name = 'OutlinePass.edge1';
    this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.texture.generateMipmaps = false;
    this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2 = new WebGLRenderTarget(Math.round(resx / 2), Math.round(resy / 2), pars);
    this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2.texture.name = 'OutlinePass.edge2';
    this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2.texture.generateMipmaps = false;

    var MAX_EDGE_THICKNESS = 4;
    var MAX_EDGE_GLOW = 4;

    this.separableBlurMaterial1 = this.getSeperableBlurMaterial(MAX_EDGE_THICKNESS);
    this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms['texSize'].value.set(resx, resy);
    this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms['kernelRadius'].value = 1;
    this.separableBlurMaterial2 = this.getSeperableBlurMaterial(MAX_EDGE_GLOW);
    this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms['texSize'].value.set(Math.round(resx / 2), Math.round(resy / 2));
    this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms['kernelRadius'].value = MAX_EDGE_GLOW;

    // Overlay material
    this.overlayMaterial = this.getOverlayMaterial();

    // copy material
    if (CopyShader === undefined)
        console.error('THREE.OutlinePass relies on CopyShader');

    var copyShader = CopyShader;

    this.copyUniforms = UniformsUtils.clone(copyShader.uniforms);
    this.copyUniforms['opacity'].value = 1.0;

    this.materialCopy = new ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: this.copyUniforms,
        vertexShader: copyShader.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: copyShader.fragmentShader,
        blending: NoBlending,
        depthTest: false,
        depthWrite: false,
        transparent: true
    });

    this.enabled = true;
    this.needsSwap = false;

    this._oldClearColor = new Color();
    this.oldClearAlpha = 1;

    this.fsQuad = new Pass.FullScreenQuad(null);

    this.tempPulseColor1 = new Color();
    this.textureMatrix = new Matrix4();

    this.floodFill = floodFill;

    function floodFill(x, y, pixelData, width, height) {
        var pixel_stack = [{ x: x, y: y }];
        var pixels = pixelData;
        var linear_cords = (y * width + x) * 4;

        var original_color = {
            r: pixels[linear_cords],
            g: pixels[linear_cords + 1],
            b: pixels[linear_cords + 2],
            a: pixels[linear_cords + 3]
        };

        var color = {
            r: 0,
            g: 0,
            b: 255,
            a: 255,
        }

        while (pixel_stack.length > 0) {
            var new_pixel = pixel_stack.shift();
            x = new_pixel.x;
            y = new_pixel.y;

            linear_cords = (y * width + x) * 4;
            while (y-- >= 0 &&
                (pixels[linear_cords + 1] == original_color.g)) {
                linear_cords -= width * 4;
            }
            linear_cords += width * 4;
            y++;

            var reached_left = false;
            var reached_right = false;
            while (y++ < height &&
                (pixels[linear_cords + 1] == original_color.g)) {
                pixels[linear_cords] = color.r;
                pixels[linear_cords + 1] = color.g;
                pixels[linear_cords + 2] = color.b;
                pixels[linear_cords + 3] = color.a;

                if (x > 0) {
                    if (pixels[linear_cords - 4] == original_color.r &&
                        pixels[linear_cords - 4 + 1] == original_color.g) {
                        if (!reached_left) {
                            pixel_stack.push({ x: x - 1, y: y });
                            reached_left = true;
                        }
                    } else if (reached_left) {
                        reached_left = false;
                    }
                }

                if (x < width - 1) {
                    if (pixels[linear_cords + 4] == original_color.r &&
                        pixels[linear_cords + 4 + 1] == original_color.g) {
                        if (!reached_right) {
                            pixel_stack.push({ x: x + 1, y: y });
                            reached_right = true;
                        }
                    } else if (reached_right) {
                        reached_right = false;
                    }
                }
                linear_cords += width * 4;
            }
        }
    }
};

OutlinePass.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(Pass.prototype), {

    constructor: OutlinePass,

    dispose: function () {

        this.renderTargetMaskBuffer.dispose();
        this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer.dispose();
        this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1.dispose();
        this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2.dispose();
        this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.dispose();
        this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2.dispose();

    },

    setSize: function (width, height) {

        this.renderTargetMaskBuffer.setSize(width, height);

        var resx = Math.round(width / this.downSampleRatio);
        var resy = Math.round(height / this.downSampleRatio);
        this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer.setSize(resx, resy);
        this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1.setSize(resx, resy);
        this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.setSize(resx, resy);
        this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms['texSize'].value.set(resx, resy);

        resx = Math.round(resx / 2);
        resy = Math.round(resy / 2);

        this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2.setSize(resx, resy);
        this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2.setSize(resx, resy);

        this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms['texSize'].value.set(resx, resy);

    },

    changeVisibilityOfSelectedObjects: function (bVisible) {

        var cache = this._visibilityCache;

        function gatherSelectedMeshesCallBack(object) {

            if (object.isMesh) {

                if (bVisible === true) {

                    object.visible = cache.get(object);

                } else {

                    cache.set(object, object.visible);
                    object.visible = bVisible;

                }

            }

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedObjects.length; i++) {

            var selectedObject = this.selectedObjects[i];
            selectedObject.traverse(gatherSelectedMeshesCallBack);

        }

    },

    changeVisibilityOfNonSelectedObjects: function (bVisible) {

        var cache = this._visibilityCache;
        var selectedMeshes = [];

        function gatherSelectedMeshesCallBack(object) {

            if (object.isMesh) selectedMeshes.push(object);

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedObjects.length; i++) {

            var selectedObject = this.selectedObjects[i];
            selectedObject.traverse(gatherSelectedMeshesCallBack);

        }

        function VisibilityChangeCallBack(object) {

            if (object.isMesh || object.isSprite) {

                // only meshes and sprites are supported by OutlinePass

                var bFound = false;

                for (var i = 0; i < selectedMeshes.length; i++) {

                    var selectedObjectId = selectedMeshes[i].id;

                    if (selectedObjectId === object.id) {

                        bFound = true;
                        break;

                    }

                }

                if (bFound === false) {

                    var visibility = object.visible;

                    if (bVisible === false || cache.get(object) === true) {

                        object.visible = bVisible;

                    }

                    cache.set(object, visibility);

                }

            } else if (object.isPoints || object.isLine) {

                // the visibilty of points and lines is always set to false in order to
                // not affect the outline computation

                if (bVisible === true) {

                    object.visible = cache.get(object); // restore

                } else {

                    cache.set(object, object.visible);
                    object.visible = bVisible;

                }

            }

        }

        this.renderScene.traverse(VisibilityChangeCallBack);

    },

    updateTextureMatrix: function () {

        this.textureMatrix.set(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,
            0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        this.textureMatrix.multiply(this.renderCamera.projectionMatrix);
        this.textureMatrix.multiply(this.renderCamera.matrixWorldInverse);

    },

    render: function (renderer, writeBuffer, readBuffer, deltaTime, maskActive) {

        if (this.selectedObjects.length > 0) {
            renderer.getClearColor(this._oldClearColor);
            this.oldClearAlpha = renderer.getClearAlpha();
            var oldAutoClear = renderer.autoClear;

            renderer.autoClear = false;

            if (maskActive) renderer.state.buffers.stencil.setTest(false);

            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);

            var currentBackground = this.renderScene.background;
            this.renderScene.background = null;

            this.renderScene.overrideMaterial = this.prepareMaskMaterial;
            this.prepareMaskMaterial.uniforms['isSelected'].value = true;

            // XXXXchange visibility SELECTED OBJECTXXXX  <- TODO: ignore object invisible
            // this.changeVisibilityOfSelectedObjects(true);
            // this._visibilityCache.clear();

            renderer.setRenderTarget(this.renderTargetMaskBuffer);
            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(this.renderScene, this.renderCamera);

            this.renderScene.background = currentBackground;
            this.renderScene.overrideMaterial = null;


            // 2. Downsample to Half resolution
            this.fsQuad.material = this.materialCopy;
            this.copyUniforms['tDiffuse'].value = this.renderTargetMaskBuffer.texture;
            renderer.setRenderTarget(this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer);
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render(renderer);


            // flood fill with randertarget buffer
            var maskBufferSize = this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer;
            var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(maskBufferSize.width * maskBufferSize.height * 4 * 4);
            renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer, 0, 0, maskBufferSize.width, maskBufferSize.height, pixelBuffer);
            this.floodFill(parseInt(this.mouse.x / 2), maskBufferSize.height - parseInt(this.mouse.y / 2), pixelBuffer, maskBufferSize.width, maskBufferSize.height);
            var expandTexture = new DataTexture(pixelBuffer, maskBufferSize.width, maskBufferSize.height, RGBAFormat);

            this.fsQuad.material = this.materialCopy;
            this.copyUniforms['tDiffuse'].value = expandTexture;
            renderer.setRenderTarget(this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer);
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render(renderer);


            // pulse
            this.tempPulseColor1.copy( this.visibleEdgeColor );

            if ( this.pulsePeriod > 0 ) {

                var scalar = ( 1 + 0.25 ) / 2 + Math.cos( performance.now() * 0.01 / this.pulsePeriod ) * ( 1.0 - 0.25 ) / 2;
                this.tempPulseColor1.multiplyScalar( scalar );

            }

            // 3. Apply Edge Detection Pass
            this.fsQuad.material = this.edgeDetectionMaterial;
            this.edgeDetectionMaterial.uniforms['maskTexture'].value = expandTexture;
            this.edgeDetectionMaterial.uniforms['texSize'].value.set(this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer.width, this.renderTargetMaskDownSampleBuffer.height);
            this.edgeDetectionMaterial.uniforms['visibleEdgeColor'].value = this.tempPulseColor1;
            renderer.setRenderTarget(this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1);
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render(renderer);

            // 4. Apply Blur on Half res
            this.fsQuad.material = this.separableBlurMaterial1;
            this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms[ 'colorTexture' ].value = this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.texture;
            this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms[ 'direction' ].value = OutlinePass.BlurDirectionX;
            this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms[ 'kernelRadius' ].value = this.edgeThickness;
            renderer.setRenderTarget( this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1 );
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render( renderer );
            this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms[ 'colorTexture' ].value = this.renderTargetBlurBuffer1.texture;
            this.separableBlurMaterial1.uniforms[ 'direction' ].value = OutlinePass.BlurDirectionY;
            renderer.setRenderTarget( this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1 );
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render( renderer );

            // Apply Blur on quarter res
            this.fsQuad.material = this.separableBlurMaterial2;
            this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms[ 'colorTexture' ].value = this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.texture;
            this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms[ 'direction' ].value = OutlinePass.BlurDirectionX;
            renderer.setRenderTarget( this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2 );
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render( renderer );
            this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms[ 'colorTexture' ].value = this.renderTargetBlurBuffer2.texture;
            this.separableBlurMaterial2.uniforms[ 'direction' ].value = OutlinePass.BlurDirectionY;
            renderer.setRenderTarget( this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2 );
            renderer.clear();
            this.fsQuad.render( renderer );

            // Blend it additively over the input texture
            this.fsQuad.material = this.overlayMaterial;
            this.overlayMaterial.uniforms[ 'maskTexture' ].value = this.renderTargetMaskBuffer.texture;
            this.overlayMaterial.uniforms[ 'edgeTexture1' ].value = this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer1.texture;
            this.overlayMaterial.uniforms[ 'edgeTexture2' ].value = this.renderTargetEdgeBuffer2.texture;
            this.overlayMaterial.uniforms[ 'edgeStrength' ].value = this.edgeStrength;
            this.overlayMaterial.uniforms[ 'edgeGlow' ].value = this.edgeGlow;


            if (maskActive) renderer.state.buffers.stencil.setTest(true);

            renderer.setRenderTarget(readBuffer);
            this.fsQuad.render(renderer);

            renderer.setClearColor(this._oldClearColor, this.oldClearAlpha);
            renderer.autoClear = oldAutoClear;

        }

        if (this.renderToScreen) {

            this.fsQuad.material = this.materialCopy;
            this.copyUniforms['tDiffuse'].value = readBuffer.texture;
            renderer.setRenderTarget(null);
            this.fsQuad.render(renderer);

        }

    },

    getPrepareMaskMaterial: function () {

        return new ShaderMaterial({

            uniforms: {
                'isSelected': { value: false },
            },

            vertexShader: [
                'void main() {',
                '   #include <begin_vertex>',
                '   #include <project_vertex>',

                '}'
            ].join('\n'),

            fragmentShader: [
                'uniform bool isSelected;',

                'void main() {',

                '   gl_FragColor = (isSelected) ? vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) : vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);',

                '}'
            ].join('\n')

        });

    },

    getEdgeDetectionMaterial: function () {

        return new ShaderMaterial({

            uniforms: {
                'maskTexture': { value: null },
                'texSize': { value: new Vector2(0.5, 0.5) },
                'visibleEdgeColor': { value: new Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) },
            },

            vertexShader:
                'varying vec2 vUv;\n\
                void main() {\n\
                    vUv = uv;\n\
                    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );\n\
                }',

            fragmentShader:
                'varying vec2 vUv;\
                uniform sampler2D maskTexture;\
                uniform vec2 texSize;\
                uniform vec3 visibleEdgeColor;\
                \
                void main() {\n\
                    vec2 invSize = 1.0 / texSize;\
                    vec4 uvOffset = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) * vec4(invSize, invSize);\
                    vec4 c1 = texture2D( maskTexture, vUv + uvOffset.xy);\
                    vec4 c2 = texture2D( maskTexture, vUv - uvOffset.xy);\
                    vec4 c3 = texture2D( maskTexture, vUv + uvOffset.yw);\
                    vec4 c4 = texture2D( maskTexture, vUv - uvOffset.yw);\
                    float diff1 = (c1.r - c2.r)*0.5;\
                    float diff2 = (c3.r - c4.r)*0.5;\
                    float d = length( vec2(diff1, diff2) );\
                    vec3 edgeColor = visibleEdgeColor;\
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(edgeColor, 1.0) * vec4(d);\
                }'
        });

    },

    getSeperableBlurMaterial: function (maxRadius) {

        return new ShaderMaterial({

            defines: {
                'MAX_RADIUS': maxRadius,
            },

            uniforms: {
                'colorTexture': { value: null },
                'texSize': { value: new Vector2(0.5, 0.5) },
                'direction': { value: new Vector2(0.5, 0.5) },
                'kernelRadius': { value: 1.0 }
            },

            vertexShader:
                'varying vec2 vUv;\n\
                void main() {\n\
                    vUv = uv;\n\
                    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );\n\
                }',

            fragmentShader:
                '#include <common>\
                varying vec2 vUv;\
                uniform sampler2D colorTexture;\
                uniform vec2 texSize;\
                uniform vec2 direction;\
                uniform float kernelRadius;\
                \
                float gaussianPdf(in float x, in float sigma) {\
                    return 0.39894 * exp( -0.5 * x * x/( sigma * sigma))/sigma;\
                }\
                void main() {\
                    vec2 invSize = 1.0 / texSize;\
                    float weightSum = gaussianPdf(0.0, kernelRadius);\
                    vec4 diffuseSum = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv) * weightSum;\
                    vec2 delta = direction * invSize * kernelRadius/float(MAX_RADIUS);\
                    vec2 uvOffset = delta;\
                    for( int i = 1; i <= MAX_RADIUS; i ++ ) {\
                        float w = gaussianPdf(uvOffset.x, kernelRadius);\
                        vec4 sample1 = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv + uvOffset);\
                        vec4 sample2 = texture2D( colorTexture, vUv - uvOffset);\
                        diffuseSum += ((sample1 + sample2) * w);\
                        weightSum += (2.0 * w);\
                        uvOffset += delta;\
                    }\
                    gl_FragColor = diffuseSum/weightSum;\
                }'
        });

    },

    getOverlayMaterial: function () {

        return new ShaderMaterial({

            uniforms: {
                'maskTexture': { value: null },
                'edgeTexture1': { value: null },
                'edgeTexture2': { value: null },
                'edgeStrength': { value: 1.0 },
                'edgeGlow': { value: 1.0 },
            },

            vertexShader:
                'varying vec2 vUv;\n\
                void main() {\n\
                    vUv = uv;\n\
                    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );\n\
                }',

            fragmentShader:
                'varying vec2 vUv;\
                uniform sampler2D maskTexture;\
                uniform sampler2D edgeTexture1;\
                uniform sampler2D edgeTexture2;\
                uniform float edgeStrength;\
                uniform float edgeGlow;\
                \
                void main() {\
                    vec4 edgeValue1 = texture2D(edgeTexture1, vUv);\
                    vec4 edgeValue2 = texture2D(edgeTexture2, vUv);\
                    vec4 maskColor = texture2D(maskTexture, vUv);\
                    float visibilityFactor = 1.0 - maskColor.g > 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.5;\
                    vec4 edgeValue = edgeValue1 + edgeValue2 * edgeGlow;\
                    vec4 finalColor = edgeStrength * maskColor.r * edgeValue;\
                    gl_FragColor = finalColor;\
                }',
            blending: AdditiveBlending,
            depthTest: false,
            depthWrite: false,
            transparent: true
        });

    },
});

OutlinePass.BlurDirectionX = new Vector2(1.0, 0.0);
OutlinePass.BlurDirectionY = new Vector2(0.0, 1.0);

export { OutlinePass };
```

And I used the flood fill from this website.
https://ben.akrin.com/canvas_fill/fill_05.html